# How Can I Submit Radio Input Values in Html Form in Flutter?

Tags: html, flutter, dart, html-parsing

I want to answer surveys on a form on a website by making an html parser on Flutter.

The html output is as follows. For example, how can I select the value of the poll with the name poll_13 as 120.

```
<div id="polls">
    <form id="polls_form_1" class="wp-polls-form" action="/index.php" method="post">
        <input type="radio" id="poll-answer-10" name="poll_13" value="117">
        <input type="radio" id="poll-answer-11" name="poll_13" value="118">
        <input type="radio" id="poll-answer-12" name="poll_13" value="119">
        <input type="radio" id="poll-answer-13" name="poll_13" value="120">
        <input type="button" name="vote" value="Vote" class="Buttons" onclick="poll_vote(13);">
    </form>
</div>
```

I was able to select the poll-answer-13 element by importing the html and http packages, but I couldn't figure out how to click and submit the form.

```
  void submitForm() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          "https://xxxx.com/poll"));
          var document = parse(response.body);
      var pollAnswer118 = document.querySelector("#poll-answer-13");
  }
```

Comment: `await http.post(url, body:{'poll_13','117'});`

Comment: @RichardHeapThis way it doesn't do post processing. You need to click onclick on the button.
onclick="poll_vote(13);

Comment: What does that javascript method do?

Comment: @RichardHeap This allows voting of a poll on an html site.

Comment: Update the question with the body of the javascript message.